# Use phpMyAdmin without frames

Tags: phpmyadmin, frames

How do I remove the frames in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: In what way is this a question?

Comment: My bad, i think you can answer your question though. You can additionally give a link to your question asked.

Comment: I +1ed your question, it would cross hundred now, you can post there now, where it belongs. It would help others too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open up /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php (that's where it's located on my Ubuntu machine). Don't forget to use sudo or be root.
2. After `unset($cfgRelation);` (line 60), add this: `$db = isset($_GET['db']) ? "&db=".$_GET['db'] : '';`
3. And just before `header('Content-Type:....`, add this: `header('Location: ' . $main_target."?token=".$_SESSION[' PMA_token '].$db); die;`

That's it. Now you can "enjoy" phpMyAdmin without the dreadful frames :)